# add class after X seconds, then remove class after X seconds continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I want to add a class to an element after 5 seconds, then after this has been added wait another 5 seconds and remove it, I want this to be done in a continuous loop. I've tried the following which adds it but then it gets stuck.

```js
function showOverlayTimer() {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      $('.kiosk-overlay').addClass('active');
      hideOverlayTimer();
    }, 1000);
}

function hideOverlayTimer() {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      $('.kiosk-overlay').removeClass('active');
      showOverlayTimer();
    }, 1000);
}

showOverlayTimer();
```

```css
.active { border: 1px solid green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kiosk-overlay">KIOSK OVERLAY</div>
```

Comment: If it's a continuous loop, why not use `setInterval` rather than repeatedly defining timeouts?

Comment: what does `it gets stuck` even mean? is the class added and removed?

Comment: your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/utno75Ly/

Comment: @JaromandaX it adds and removes constantly

Comment: yes, isn't that what you wanted? after 4 seconds, add it, after 4 seconds remove it, and repeat

Comment: Converted your code to a snippet - it does exactly what you asked for "*add class after X seconds, then remove class after X seconds continuously*"

Comment: Yeah, this seems to work, can you explain what if anything differs from what you're experiencing? We'll then need a [mcve]

Comment: From close vote: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behaviour, a **specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."* - there's no description of a problem here and the provided code matches the desired output as described in the question/title.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setInterval` to `toggleClass`:

```js
setInterval(function () {
    $('.kiosk-overlay').toggleClass('active');
}, 5000)
```

```css
.kiosk-overlay:before {
  content: 'Inactive';
  display: inline;
  color: red;
}

.kiosk-overlay.active:before {
  content: 'Active';
  display: inline;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kiosk-overlay"></div>
```